# Correlation coefficient of x and y

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value, correlation, poisson-process

If we have $$ X\sim Poisson(\lambda), Y|X = x\sim Binomial(x+1,p) $$ What is the 
correlation coefficient of  X and Y?

So I used $$\rho=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(x)Var(Y)}} = \frac{E[X[E[Y|X]]-E[X]E[E[Y|X]]}{\sqrt{E[X](E[E[Y|X]^2] -E[E[Y|X]]^2)}}$$
Is this right? Because I got a wacky answer, and is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct approach, but use the following.
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X)&=\lambda
\\[1ex]
\mathsf{Var}(X)&=\lambda&&=\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2
\\[1ex]
\mathsf E(Y\mid X)&=(X+1)\,p
\\[1ex]
\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X)&=(X+1)\,p\,(1-p)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)
\\[1ex]
&=\mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X))-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))
\\[2ex]
\mathsf {Var}(Y)
  &=\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))&&\star
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now :D